# how to move a file whoose name is given by user from one folder to another in c++

Tags: c++

i am new to programming, and i was making a program in which i made the user enter the name of file and then i want to move the file (into a folder known as item) . how should i do this ?
i have tried to use the rename function but i am unable to do it.

```
    string name;
int passcode;
int accnumber;

clrscr ();

system("title Stock Management Program (Creating an account) ");

cout << "Enter Name:" ; // getting basic info
cin >> name;
cout << endl;

cout <<"Enter Account Number:";
cin >> accnumber;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter your passcode (only numbers):";
cin >> passcode;

ifstream errcheck;
errcheck.open(name);

if (errcheck.fail())
{
    ofstream createacc; // creating account using fstream
    createacc.open (name);
    createacc << accnumber << endl;
    createacc << passcode << endl;
    createacc.close (); 

    string newname = "item\" + name; //problem
    int rename ( const char * name, const char * newname ); // PROBLEM
}
{
    cout << "Sorry account already exists! ";
    pause ();
}
```

Comment: i am unable to create a string containing "item\"

Comment: This really should be closed - it's been abandoned in horribly mixed up form for the better part of a year, and reflects a complete lack of understanding of programming - we have an attempt to use a function prototype as an invocation, a complete misunderstanding of what system() does, etc - the poster has either learned in the meantime, or lost interest, so the question is of no use now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a problem because backslash is an escape symbol (it will treat next symbols as text), use `\\` it will be treated as single backslash.

```
string newname = "item\" + name; //problem

string newname2 = "item\\" + name; //ok
```

For you perpose it's better to use a file system lib, for example [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)